# What's a pushlock?

Tags: architecture, synchronization, internals

Pushlocks are used internally by windows as synchronization primitives for some of its operations, specifically as part of the memory manager.

What exactly is a pushlock? How is it different from a spinlock?

Comment: Who thought that this was not programming related?

Comment: Maybe they misread a letter or two.

Answer (score 1):

Pushlocks, together with mutexes, synchronization events, semaphores and executive resources are **WAIT-based.**

In the other hand, spinlocks, queue spinlocks are, etc. are, well... of "spin" type, implemented by busy-waiting (spinning).

The choice of a particular synchronization primitive is discussed in depth in [this article](https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2015-issue3/the-state-of-synchronization/).